# Como fazer o ciclo for em lisp?

Tags: lisp

Estou a aprender `lisp` na universidade recentemente e estou com alguns problemas em me adaptar a esta linguagem.
O ciclo `let` nesta linguagem funciona como um for em java? Se sim podem me mostrar um exemplo que dê para perceber mais ou menos como funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Este [link](http://www.dca.ufrn.br/~adelardo/lisp/) contém uma grande quantidade de informações sobre essa linguagem. Inclusive uma explicação sobre interações, no item 2.19 você pode ver como criar um `loop` que seria equivalente ao `for` em java.

Exemplo:

Imprimindo números do 10 ao 20.

```
(loop for a from 10 to 20
    do (print a)
)
```

O código acima é equivalente ao seguinte código em java:

```
for(int i = 10; i <= 20; i++){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Respostas contendo apenas links são desencorajadas, pois se um dia o link quebrar, a resposta perderá sentido. Sugiro colocar um exemplo de código aqui.

Comment: @Renan, Obrigado pela dica. Vou editar minha resposta colocando um exemplo.